# PL/SQL query on machine linux bash that prints in a .txt

Tags: sql, bash, sh

```
spool 1.txt REPLACE

set serveroutput on
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AAAAA');
end;
/
spool off
```

Does someone know why this query doesn't run?

I have made a .sh script that opens this .sql query but it doesn't return any response.

And the .sh is :

```
sqlplus -s user/pass@database @sh.sql
```

Comment: Hi Delta, "opens" or "executes" ? Can you please post snippet of your .sh file as well? Also, worth reading the following guides, as they help us help you better! [creating minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script I wrote and tested, adjust it to suit your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script started."

typeset db_conn_str="${user}/${passwd}@${db}"
typeset sql_query="CONNECT ${db_conn_str};
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL script launched via foobar.sh');
    END;
    /
"
echo "${sql_query}" | sqlplus /nolog

echo "Script finished."
```